# How to interpret `apt-cache rdepends` to pinpoint dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-dependent-packages-reverse-dependencies advises `apt-cache rdepends` but does not explain how to interpret the output. The output consists on lines with no indentation and two spaces one. But dependencies form a tree-line structure, any way to see output that way? How to interpret w/out tree? For example:

I run:

```
~$ apt-cache rdepends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances libpulse0:i386
```

Got ~1k lines (with only `--recurse` option output is ~500k lines). Around line 300th (full output at the end):

```
...
Reverse Depends:
  libpcaudio-dev:i386
  espeak-ng:i386
  libespeak-ng1:i386
libcanberra-pulse:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio
Reverse Depends:
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
...
```

Before that I have not noticed non-i386 packages listed, so first one is `pulseaudio`. How to find out which package requires `pulseaudio`? Indentation of a line immediately preceding is different from previous once, no indentation for `libcanberra-pulse:i386`. Does it mean `libcanberra-pulse:i386` requires `pulseaudio`? The output below of `apt-cache show` lists it as dependency, however output `apt-cache rdepends` does not list another dependencies, e.g. `libc6`.

```
$ apt-cache show libcanberra-pulse:i386
Package: libcanberra-pulse
Architecture: i386
Version: 0.30-7ubuntu1
Multi-Arch: same
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: libcanberra
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GNOME Maintainers <pkg-gnome-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 49
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libcanberra0 (= 0.30-7ubuntu1), libpulse0 (>= 0.99.1), pulseaudio
```

Full output:

```
~$ apt-cache rdepends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances libpulse0:i386
libpulse0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  wine-stable-i386:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
  pulseaudio-module-lirc:i386
  pulseaudio-module-jack:i386
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings:i386
  pulseaudio-equalizer:i386
  pulseaudio-utils:i386
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
  libpulsedsp:i386
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386
  libpulse-dev:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
  pulseaudio-module-lirc:i386
  pulseaudio-module-jack:i386
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings:i386
  pulseaudio-equalizer:i386
  openjdk-8-jre:i386
  libavdevice58:i386
  pulseaudio-utils:i386
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
  libpulsedsp:i386
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386
  libpulse-dev:i386
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:i386
  libpulse-dev:i386
  vlc-plugin-base:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
  pulseaudio-module-lirc:i386
  pulseaudio-module-jack:i386
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings:i386
  pulseaudio-equalizer:i386
  openmpt123:i386
  openjdk-8-jre:i386
  mpg123:i386
  lmms:i386
  libwine-development:i386
  libwine:i386
  libsox-fmt-pulse:i386
  libsoundio1:i386
  libsdl2-2.0-0:i386
  libsdl1.2debian:i386
  librtaudio6:i386
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins:i386
  libqt5multimedia5:i386
  libmikmod3:i386
  libfluidsynth2:i386
  libespeak1:i386
  libavdevice58:i386
  gpac-modules-base:i386
  speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:i386
  pulseaudio-utils:i386
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
  libpulsedsp:i386
  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386
  libasound2-plugins:i386
  libpcaudio0:i386
  libcanberra-pulse:i386
  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:i386
wine-stable-i386:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:i386
Reverse Depends:
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-module-lirc:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-module-jack:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-module-gsettings:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-equalizer:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-utils:i386
Reverse Depends:
  pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio:i386
Reverse Depends:
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
  pulseaudio-module-lirc:i386
  pulseaudio-module-jack:i386
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings:i386
  pulseaudio-equalizer:i386
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:i386
    pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:i386
    pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
    pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-lirc:i386
    pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-jack:i386
    pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings:i386
    pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-equalizer:i386
    pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop:i386
  pulseaudio-module-lirc:i386
  pulseaudio-module-jack:i386
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings:i386
  pulseaudio-equalizer:i386
  libcanberra-pulse:i386
    pulseaudio
libpulsedsp:i386
Reverse Depends:
  pulseaudio-utils:i386
  pulseaudio-utils:i386
  pulseaudio-utils:i386
libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libpulse-dev:i386
  libpulse-dev:i386
  libpulse-dev:i386
libpulse-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  qtmultimedia5-dev:i386
  libsdl2-dev:i386
  libsdl1.2-dev:i386
  librtaudio-dev:i386
  libefl-all-dev:i386
openjdk-8-jre:i386
Reverse Depends:
  openjdk-8-jdk:i386
  openjdk-8-demo:i386
  openjdk-8-jdk:i386
  openjdk-8-demo:i386
libavdevice58:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libavdevice-dev:i386
  ffmpeg:i386
  ffmpeg:i386
  libavdevice-dev:i386
  gpac:i386
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:i386
Reverse Depends:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg:i386
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg:i386
vlc-plugin-base:i386
Reverse Depends:
  vlc:i386
openmpt123:i386
Reverse Depends:
mpg123:i386
Reverse Depends:
lmms:i386
Reverse Depends:
libwine-development:i386
Reverse Depends:
  wine32-development:i386
  libwine-development-dev:i386
  dxvk-wine32-development:i386
  carla-bridge-wine32:i386
libwine:i386
Reverse Depends:
  wine32:i386
  lmms-vst-server:i386
  libwine-dev:i386
libsox-fmt-pulse:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsox-fmt-all:i386
  sox:i386
libsoundio1:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsoundio-dev:i386
  lmms:i386
libsdl2-2.0-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libavdevice58:i386
  ffmpeg:i386
  pcsx2:i386
  libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0:i386
  libsdl2-net-2.0-0:i386
  libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0:i386
  libsdl2-image-2.0-0:i386
  libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0:i386
  libsdl2-dev:i386
  libmikmod3:i386
  bochs:i386
  libfluidsynth2:i386
  libfaudio0:i386
  libavdevice58:i386
  fluidsynth:i386
  ffmpeg:i386
  bochs-sdl:i386
libsdl1.2debian:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl1.2-dev:i386
  dgen:i386
  zsnes:i386
  vlc-plugin-base:i386
  smpeg-plaympeg:i386
  smpeg-gtv:i386
  mpeg2dec:i386
  mjpegtools:i386
  lmms:i386
  libtheora-bin:i386
  libsmpeg0:i386
  adlibtracker2:i386
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
  libsdl-sound1.2:i386
  libsdl-sge:i386
  libsdl-pango1:i386
  libsdl-ocaml:i386
  libsdl-net1.2:i386
  libsdl-mixer1.2:i386
  libsdl-image1.2:i386
  libsdl-gst:i386
  libsdl-gfx1.2-5:i386
  libsdl-console:i386
  liblavplay-2.1-0:i386
  libdv-bin:i386
  libde265-examples:i386
  gpac-modules-base:i386
  fenix-plugins:i386
  fenix-plugin-mpeg:i386
  fenix:i386
librtaudio6:i386
Reverse Depends:
  librtaudio-dev:i386
  stk:i386
  libstk-4.6.1:i386
libqt5multimedia5-plugins:i386
Reverse Depends:
  qtmultimedia5-examples:i386
libqt5multimedia5:i386
Reverse Depends:
  qtmultimedia5-examples:i386
  qtmultimedia5-dev:i386
  qml-module-qtmultimedia:i386
  qml-module-qtaudioengine:i386
  python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg:i386
  python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia:i386
  libqt5multimediawidgets5:i386
  libqt5multimediaquick5:i386
  libqt5multimediagsttools5:i386
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins:i386
libmikmod3:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libmikmod-dev:i386
  libsdl-sound1.2:i386
  libsdl-mixer1.2:i386
libfluidsynth2:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libfluidsynth-dev:i386
  vlc-plugin-fluidsynth:i386
  lmms:i386
  libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0:i386
  libsdl-mixer1.2:i386
  fluidsynth:i386
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386
libespeak1:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libespeak-dev:i386
  speech-dispatcher-espeak:i386
    libespeak-ng-libespeak1:i386
  espeak:i386
    libespeak-ng-libespeak1:i386
gpac-modules-base:i386
Reverse Depends:
  gpac:i386
speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins:i386
Reverse Depends:
  speech-dispatcher-ibmtts:i386
  speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-ibmtts:i386
libasound2-plugins:i386
Reverse Depends:
  wine-stable-i386:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio:i386
libpcaudio0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libpcaudio-dev:i386
  espeak-ng:i386
  libespeak-ng1:i386
libcanberra-pulse:i386
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio
Reverse Depends:
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
  pulseaudio-module-raop
  pulseaudio-module-lirc
  pulseaudio-module-jack
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings
  pulseaudio-equalizer
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-lirc
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-jack
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-equalizer
    pulseaudio:i386
  plasma-pa
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  x2gothinclient-minidesktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  x2gothinclient-chroot
    pulseaudio:i386
  vanilla-gnome-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntukylin-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-unity-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-mate-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-mate-core
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-budgie-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseeffects
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
  pulseaudio-module-raop
  pulseaudio-module-lirc
  pulseaudio-module-jack
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings
  pulseaudio-equalizer
  plasma-pa
    pulseaudio:i386
  pavucontrol-qt
    pulseaudio:i386
  osspd-pulseaudio
    pulseaudio:i386
  mkchromecast-pulseaudio
    pulseaudio:i386
  lubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  kubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
 |kde-telepathy-call-ui
    pulseaudio:i386
  indicator-sound
    pulseaudio:i386
  gqrx-sdr
    pulseaudio:i386
  gnome-core
    pulseaudio:i386
  cairo-dock-impulse-plug-in
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  libcanberra-pulse
    pulseaudio:i386
  chromium
    pulseaudio:i386
qtmultimedia5-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl2-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl2-ttf-dev:i386
  libsdl2-net-dev:i386
  libsdl2-mixer-dev:i386
  libsdl2-image-dev:i386
  libsdl2-gfx-dev:i386
libsdl1.2-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsmpeg-dev:i386
  libsdl-console-dev:i386
  libsdl-ttf2.0-dev:i386
  libsdl-sound1.2-dev:i386
  libsdl-sge-dev:i386
  libsdl-pango-dev:i386
  libsdl-ocaml-dev:i386
  libsdl-net1.2-dev:i386
  libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:i386
  libsdl-image1.2-dev:i386
  libsdl-gfx1.2-dev:i386
librtaudio-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libstk-dev:i386
  librtmidi-dev:i386
libefl-all-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
openjdk-8-jdk:i386
Reverse Depends:
openjdk-8-demo:i386
Reverse Depends:
libavdevice-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
ffmpeg:i386
Reverse Depends:
gpac:i386
Reverse Depends:
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good-dbg:i386
Reverse Depends:
vlc:i386
Reverse Depends:
wine32-development:i386
Reverse Depends:
  wine32-development-preloader:i386
libwine-development-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  wine32-development-tools:i386
dxvk-wine32-development:i386
Reverse Depends:
carla-bridge-wine32:i386
Reverse Depends:
  carla-bridge-win32:i386
wine32:i386
Reverse Depends:
  lmms-vst-server:i386
  wine32-preloader:i386
lmms-vst-server:i386
Reverse Depends:
libwine-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  wine32-tools:i386
libsox-fmt-all:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsox-dev:i386
sox:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsoundio-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
pcsx2:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl2-ttf-dev:i386
libsdl2-net-2.0-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl2-net-dev:i386
libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl2-mixer-dev:i386
libsdl2-image-2.0-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl2-image-dev:i386
libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl2-gfx-dev:i386
bochs:i386
Reverse Depends:
  bochs-x:i386
  bochs-wx:i386
  bochs-term:i386
  bochs-sdl:i386
libfaudio0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libwine:i386
  wine-stable-i386:i386
  libwine-development:i386
  libfaudio-dev:i386
fluidsynth:i386
Reverse Depends:
bochs-sdl:i386
Reverse Depends:
dgen:i386
Reverse Depends:
zsnes:i386
Reverse Depends:
smpeg-plaympeg:i386
Reverse Depends:
smpeg-gtv:i386
Reverse Depends:
mpeg2dec:i386
Reverse Depends:
mjpegtools:i386
Reverse Depends:
  mjpegtools-gtk:i386
libtheora-bin:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsmpeg0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsmpeg-dev:i386
  smpeg-plaympeg:i386
  smpeg-gtv:i386
  fenix-plugin-mpeg:i386
adlibtracker2:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-dev:i386
  libsdl-ocaml:i386
libsdl-sound1.2:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-sound1.2-dev:i386
libsdl-sge:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-sge-dev:i386
libsdl-pango1:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-pango-dev:i386
libsdl-ocaml:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-net1.2:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-net1.2-dev:i386
  fenix-plugins:i386
libsdl-mixer1.2:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-ocaml:i386
  libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:i386
  fenix:i386
  fenix-plugin-mpeg:i386
libsdl-image1.2:i386
Reverse Depends:
  vlc-plugin-base:i386
  libsdl-sge:i386
  libsdl-ocaml:i386
  libsdl-image1.2-dev:i386
  libsdl-console:i386
  fenix-plugins:i386
libsdl-gst:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-gfx1.2-5:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-ocaml:i386
  libsdl-gfx1.2-dev:i386
libsdl-console:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-console-dev:i386
liblavplay-2.1-0:i386
Reverse Depends:
  mjpegtools:i386
  libmjpegtools-dev:i386
libdv-bin:i386
Reverse Depends:
libde265-examples:i386
Reverse Depends:
fenix-plugins:i386
Reverse Depends:
fenix-plugin-mpeg:i386
Reverse Depends:
fenix:i386
Reverse Depends:
  pixbros:i386
  pixfrogger:i386
stk:i386
Reverse Depends:
  lmms:i386
libstk-4.6.1:i386
Reverse Depends:
  stk:i386
  lmms:i386
  libstk-dev:i386
qtmultimedia5-examples:i386
Reverse Depends:
qml-module-qtmultimedia:i386
Reverse Depends:
  qtmultimedia5-examples:i386
qml-module-qtaudioengine:i386
Reverse Depends:
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg:i386
Reverse Depends:
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia:i386
Reverse Depends:
  python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg:i386
libqt5multimediawidgets5:i386
Reverse Depends:
  python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia:i386
  qtmultimedia5-examples:i386
  qtmultimedia5-dev:i386
  python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia-dbg:i386
  libqt5multimediagsttools5:i386
libqt5multimediaquick5:i386
Reverse Depends:
  qtmultimedia5-dev:i386
  qml-module-qtmultimedia:i386
libqt5multimediagsttools5:i386
Reverse Depends:
  qtmultimedia5-dev:i386
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins:i386
libmikmod-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:i386
libfluidsynth-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
vlc-plugin-fluidsynth:i386
Reverse Depends:
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:i386
Reverse Depends:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg:i386
libespeak-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-espeak:i386
Reverse Depends:
libespeak-ng-libespeak1:i386
Reverse Depends:
espeak:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-ibmtts:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher:i386
Reverse Depends:
  speech-dispatcher-baratinoo:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-pico:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-pico:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-ibmtts:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-ibmtts:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-kali:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-kali:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-flite:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-espeak:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-cicero:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-baratinoo:i386
    speech-dispatcher
  speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng:i386
    speech-dispatcher
libpcaudio-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
espeak-ng:i386
Reverse Depends:
libespeak-ng1:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libespeak-ng-dev:i386
  libespeak-ng-libespeak1:i386
  espeak-ng:i386
  speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng:i386
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Reverse Depends:
  lubuntu-desktop
  gnome-core
pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
Reverse Depends:
  paprefs
  pulseaudio-module-raop
  pulseaudio-module-raop
  pulseaudio-module-raop
pulseaudio-module-raop
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-module-lirc
Reverse Depends:
pulseaudio-module-jack
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-controls
  ubuntustudio-controls
pulseaudio-module-gsettings
Reverse Depends:
  paprefs
pulseaudio-equalizer
Reverse Depends:
plasma-pa
Reverse Depends:
 |kde-standard
 |kdemultimedia
ubuntu-desktop-minimal
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntu-desktop
  ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop
x2gothinclient-minidesktop
Reverse Depends:
  x2gothinclient-chroot
x2gothinclient-chroot
Reverse Depends:
vanilla-gnome-desktop
Reverse Depends:
ubuntukylin-desktop
Reverse Depends:
ubuntu-unity-desktop
Reverse Depends:
ubuntu-mate-desktop
Reverse Depends:
ubuntu-mate-core
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntu-mate-desktop
ubuntu-budgie-desktop
Reverse Depends:
pulseeffects
Reverse Depends:
pavucontrol-qt
Reverse Depends:
 |lxqt
  lubuntu-desktop
osspd-pulseaudio
Reverse Depends:
 |osspd
mkchromecast-pulseaudio
Reverse Depends:
lubuntu-desktop
Reverse Depends:
kubuntu-desktop
Reverse Depends:
kde-telepathy-call-ui
Reverse Depends:
indicator-sound
Reverse Depends:
  unity-control-center
gqrx-sdr
Reverse Depends:
gnome-core
Reverse Depends:
  gnome
cairo-dock-impulse-plug-in
Reverse Depends:
  cairo-dock-plug-ins
libcanberra-pulse
Reverse Depends:
  cinnamon
  plasma-pa
  ubuntukylin-desktop
  ubuntu-mate-desktop
  ubuntu-mate-core
  ubuntu-budgie-desktop
  plasma-pa
  gnome-core
  cinnamon
chromium
Reverse Depends:
 |x2gothinclient-minidesktop
 |gnome-core
 |cinnamon-desktop-environment
  chromium-dbg
libsdl2-ttf-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl2-net-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl2-mixer-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl2-image-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl2-gfx-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsmpeg-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-console-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-ttf2.0-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-ocaml-dev:i386
libsdl-sound1.2-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-sge-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-pango-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-ocaml-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-net1.2-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsdl-mixer1.2-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-ocaml-dev:i386
libsdl-image1.2-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-ocaml-dev:i386
  libsdl-console-dev:i386
libsdl-gfx1.2-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libsdl-ocaml-dev:i386
libstk-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libstk0-dev:i386
librtmidi-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libstk-dev:i386
wine32-development-preloader:i386
Reverse Depends:
wine32-development-tools:i386
Reverse Depends:
carla-bridge-win32:i386
Reverse Depends:
wine32-preloader:i386
Reverse Depends:
wine32-tools:i386
Reverse Depends:
libsox-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
bochs-x:i386
Reverse Depends:
bochs-wx:i386
Reverse Depends:
 |bochs:i386
bochs-term:i386
Reverse Depends:
libfaudio-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
mjpegtools-gtk:i386
Reverse Depends:
libmjpegtools-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
pixbros:i386
Reverse Depends:
pixfrogger:i386
Reverse Depends:
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-dbg:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-baratinoo:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher
Reverse Depends:
  speech-dispatcher-baratinoo
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  orca
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-pico
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-pico
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speechd-up
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-kali
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-kali
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-flite
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-festival
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-espeak
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-cicero
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-baratinoo
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  orca
    speech-dispatcher:i386
  speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
    speech-dispatcher:i386
speech-dispatcher-pico:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-kali:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-flite:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-cicero:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng:i386
Reverse Depends:
libespeak-ng-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
  libespeak-ng-libespeak-dev:i386
paprefs
Reverse Depends:
ubuntustudio-controls
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-installer
kde-standard
Reverse Depends:
  kde-full
kdemultimedia
Reverse Depends:
  kde-full
ubuntu-gnome-desktop
Reverse Depends:
lxqt
Reverse Depends:
osspd
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-video
  ubuntustudio-audio
  acfax
 |libsnack-oss
unity-control-center
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntu-unity-desktop
 |indicator-bluetooth
gnome
Reverse Depends:
cairo-dock-plug-ins
Reverse Depends:
  cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-mono
  cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-vala
  cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-ruby
  cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-python
  cairo-dock
cinnamon
Reverse Depends:
  cinnamon-dbg
  cinnamon-core
  cinnamon-dbg
  cinnamon-core
  mint-meta-cinnamon
cinnamon-desktop-environment
Reverse Depends:
chromium-dbg
Reverse Depends:
libstk0-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-baratinoo
Reverse Depends:
orca
Reverse Depends:
  gnome
  gnome-orca
  orca-sops
  gnome-orca
speech-dispatcher-pico
Reverse Depends:
speechd-up
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-kali
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-flite
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-festival
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-espeak
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-cicero
Reverse Depends:
speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng
Reverse Depends:
libespeak-ng-libespeak-dev:i386
Reverse Depends:
ubuntustudio-installer
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-default-settings
  ubuntustudio-menu
  ubuntustudio-default-settings
  ubuntustudio-menu
kde-full
Reverse Depends:
ubuntustudio-video
Reverse Depends:
ubuntustudio-audio
Reverse Depends:
acfax
Reverse Depends:
libsnack-oss
Reverse Depends:
 |tcl-snack
indicator-bluetooth
Reverse Depends:
  unity-control-center
cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-mono
Reverse Depends:
cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-vala
Reverse Depends:
cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-ruby
Reverse Depends:
cairo-dock-dbus-plug-in-interface-python
Reverse Depends:
cairo-dock
Reverse Depends:
cinnamon-dbg
Reverse Depends:
cinnamon-core
Reverse Depends:
  cinnamon-desktop-environment
  cinnamon-desktop-environment
mint-meta-cinnamon
Reverse Depends:
  cinnamon-desktop-environment
gnome-orca
Reverse Depends:
orca-sops
Reverse Depends:
ubuntustudio-default-settings
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-lightdm-theme
  ubuntustudio-lightdm-theme
  ubuntustudio-desktop
  ubuntustudio-desktop-core
ubuntustudio-menu
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-default-settings
  ubuntustudio-default-settings
  ubuntustudio-menu-add
  ubuntustudio-branding-common
tcl-snack
Reverse Depends:
  python3-tksnack
  wavesurfer
  transcriber
  tcl-snack-dev
ubuntustudio-lightdm-theme
Reverse Depends:
ubuntustudio-desktop
Reverse Depends:
ubuntustudio-desktop-core
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-desktop
ubuntustudio-menu-add
Reverse Depends:
  ubuntustudio-menu
  ubuntustudio-menu
ubuntustudio-branding-common
Reverse Depends:
python3-tksnack
Reverse Depends:
wavesurfer
Reverse Depends:
transcriber
Reverse Depends:
tcl-snack-dev
Reverse Depends:
~$
```

Comment: surely if `a` reverse depends on `b` then on search for packages that need `a` there is no need to show other dependencies of `b` except `a`. it is mind twisting for me to visualize that clearly w/out practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can produce graphical output with `apt-rdepends`’ `--dotty` or `--xvcg` options; this outputs information which can be post-processed with other tools to produce a node-and-edge representation (reminiscent of a tree or bush).

The textual output shows each package, not indented, then its reverse dependencies, indented. The `--recurse` flag causes each reverse dependency to be processed as well. A reverse dependency of X is a package Y where Y depends on X, which is the opposite of what `apt show` displays.

To find out which packages require `pulseaudio`, look at the list of reverse dependencies immediately following it:

```
pulseaudio
Reverse Depends:
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
  pulseaudio-module-raop
  pulseaudio-module-lirc
  pulseaudio-module-jack
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings
  pulseaudio-equalizer
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-raop
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-lirc
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-jack
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-equalizer
    pulseaudio:i386
  plasma-pa
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  x2gothinclient-minidesktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  x2gothinclient-chroot
    pulseaudio:i386
  vanilla-gnome-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntukylin-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-unity-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-mate-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-mate-core
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-budgie-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
  pulseeffects
    pulseaudio:i386
  pulseaudio-module-zeroconf
  pulseaudio-module-raop
  pulseaudio-module-lirc
  pulseaudio-module-jack
  pulseaudio-module-gsettings
  pulseaudio-equalizer
  plasma-pa
    pulseaudio:i386
  pavucontrol-qt
    pulseaudio:i386
  osspd-pulseaudio
    pulseaudio:i386
  mkchromecast-pulseaudio
    pulseaudio:i386
  lubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  kubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
 |kde-telepathy-call-ui
    pulseaudio:i386
  indicator-sound
    pulseaudio:i386
  gqrx-sdr
    pulseaudio:i386
  gnome-core
    pulseaudio:i386
  cairo-dock-impulse-plug-in
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop-minimal
    pulseaudio:i386
  ubuntu-desktop
    pulseaudio:i386
  libcanberra-pulse
    pulseaudio:i386
  chromium
    pulseaudio:i386
```

The packages without a double-indented `…:i386` mention are those which depend on the native `pulseaudio`. Those a double-indented `…:i386` are those which are (potential) reverse dependencies of the `i386` package; most of those are repeated, since they are reverse dependencies of both `pulseaudio:amd64` and `pulseaudio:i386`.